# Best translation to russian: "hey, doodz!"

Tags: перевод, сленг

Как перевести на русский сленговый возглас: **hey, doodz!**

Желательно, чтобы перевод максимально сохранил не только собственно само значение, но также и искаженное написание, ну типа: **эй, пацаки!**

Desirable translation should keep not only meaning of phrase but also distorted spelling :)

Comment: Как насчёт «Эй, чювоки!» или «Эй, патсоны!»

Comment: «Патсоны» на письме похожи на каких-то симпсонов, я бы и не понял сразу, что имеется ввиду. В отличие от _doodz_, которых по другому и не прочтешь. Уж лучше тогда «потцаны». Хотя мне эстетически больше нравится не коверкать корни слов, есть много других приемов, например:      «эййпацаны!».

Comment: @J-mster - «Потцаны» несёт негативные коннотации, «поц», «пот».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Здесь может быть несколько вариантов.

Начнём с doodz (dudes?).
Можно использовать слово "пацаны", и можно использовать "чуваки". Зависит от круга общения. Если происхождение парней скорее относится к рабочему классу (if you know what I mean :) ), то скорее подойдёт "пацаны". Если публика более хипповая, то лучше использовать чуваки.

Насчёт hey. Опять же зависит от конеткста. Если просто окликнуть, то так "хей" и будет. Если это приветсвтвие, то можно сказать "здорово" или производные "даров", "дарофф".

Ну и желательно конечно не обращаться так к незнакомым пацанам и чувакам. Можно больно получить по голове.

Answer (score 2):

По крайней мере в интернетах наиболее популярным будет, пожалуй, "поцоны", или даже "посоны".
Я бы перевёл как "чё как, поцоны?"

Answer (score 1):

С литературной точки зрения, искажение написания в русском тексте - не нормально.
Если это необходимо для указания на принадлежность к очень специфической социальной группе с определенным жаргоном - это одно. В противном случае, лучше обойтись обычной фразой: "Эй, пацаны" или "Эй, братва".